# Use Legacy Facebook "Share" Button Not Facebook "Like"

Tags: django, facebook-sharer

I want to use "Share on Facebook" feature, instead of new "FB Like", in my django application.
But I can't find how I can implement it and set description, title and image to share.

Can anyone help me?

**UPDATE**

I'm doing how DeLonge says. Here's the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
    <title>Bra</title>
    <link rel="image_src" href="http://site.com/images/logo.jpg" />
    <meta name="description" content="description here">
</head>

<body>
    <a name="fb_share" type="button" share_url="http://www.sharedomain.com/path/" href="http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=http:/www.sharedomain.com/path&amp;src=sp" style="text-decoration: none; ">Share</a><script src="http://static.ak.fbcdn.net/con
nect.php/js/FB.Share" type="text/javascript"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

But when I click on the button I see this wrong result:

[image]

Ideas?

Comment: It looks like the code and everything is correct. The only thing that you've missed is that you need to replace "sharedomain.com" and the URL for the image with your own links and images. Once a properly-referenced image and page is linked then the thumbnail/description will appear.

Comment: @DeLonge it works if I hardcode the URL. But I need to share a dynamic URL like site.com/profile/<username> (with profile/{{user.username}}) How can I fix?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I agree the "share" button is much more useful in certain situations. See code:

```
<a name="fb_share" type="button_count" share_url="http://www.sharedomain.com/path/" href="http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u={INSERT ENCODED share_url HERE}&amp;src=sp" style="text-decoration: none; ">Share</a>
<script src="http://static.ak.fbcdn.net/connect.php/js/FB.Share" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Types include: 1) button_count 2) button 3) link.

The title will come from the page itself. However, to add an icon image simply add the following to your HTML `<head>`:

```
<link rel="image_src" href="http://www.sharedomain.com/path/thumbnail.jpg" />
```

I know you are developing in django and I recommend that you hardcode the FB Share button. This is because Facebook is no longer pushing it and most of the APIs are disappearing for it.

Comment: Was a facebook's cache problem. Now it's ok. Thank you dude.